# My third and fourth command line arguments are not being detected in my C++ code

Tags: c++11, file-io, ofstream

I've wrote some code to output certain students' grades if they're in between a lower bound and upper bound. I don't get any errors when I'm compiling the program but it's not writing to my csv file.

I suspect that there is a problem with my if-statement, where I wrote if(argv[3] && argv[4]) because it's just not executing this part of the code. Argv3 and 4 would be "D A" in the code. So I'd write:
g++ -std=c++11 studentData.cpp
and then:
./a.out output.csv D A

```
   ofstream out_file;
   out_file.open(argv[2]);
   if(argv[3] && argv[4]){
      
      string lower = argv[3];
      string upper = argv[4];
      int x = calcNum(lower);
      int y = calcNum(upper);
      cout << "lower is: " << lower << endl;
      cout << "upper is: " << upper << endl;
   
      for(int i= 0; i < length; i++){
       if(students[i].average > x && students[i].average < y){
        
        
        out_file << students[i].studentName << " earned " << students[i].average << " which is an " << calcLetter(students[i].average) << endl;
       }
       
      }
   
  }
   else {
        cout << "Argv3 and Argv4 have not been detected";
          }
          
   out_file.close();

}
```

Comment: Please update your question with a smaller amount of code which has the same symptoms.

Comment: `Argv3 and 4 would be "D A" in the code`. What makes you think this?

Comment: I was just using D and A as an example

Comment: ok I'll shorten it

Comment: Yes, but given that you actually used `"D A"`, what makes you think they will pop up in Argv[3] and Argv[4]?

Comment: Because they'd be the third and fourth command line arguments I wrote, right? With my first being /a.out second output.csv then third D and fourth A

Comment: `./a.out output.csv D A` would put `output.csv` into `argv[1]`, `D` into `argv[2]` and `A` into `argv[3]`. `argv[4]` should be `nullptr`. Recall that in C++ array indexes are zero-based.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik you're right! Thanks for clarifying. Now I have to deal with my 2nd problem.. The code isn't writing to my output file 